# How do i create multiple buttons powered with javascript to display text in innerhtml?

Tags: javascript, button, innerhtml

I have created a simple website for learning purposes with 2 buttons (2 awnsers on a question), let's say:

Button **A** and Button **B**

When you click on **A** it will display answer A inside a div on my website by innerHtml, and when you click on **B** it will display answer B or replace awnser A with awnser B inside the innerHtml and vice versa.

So far i thought i knew how it was working by using some scripts i found on Stackoverflow.

But now i want to create 2 more buttons like above to for question 2 with the same system as mentionent above

So a button C and D, but it keep's interfering with button A and B.

I hope someone here can help me create a page that can onclick display the awnser of question 2, underneith the awnser of question 1 without interfering.

Now i am using the code shown below fot question 1:

```
<button id="choiceA" class="Button" question-one="Awnser 1" onclick="questionOne(this)">
   Q 1 choice A
  </button>

  <button id="ChoiceB" class="Button" question-one="Awnser 2" onclick="questionOne(this)">
    Q1 choice B
  </button>
```

And here's the script:

```
function questionOne(elem) {
  var x = document.getElementById("questionOne");
  var description = elem.getAttribute('question-one');
  x.innerHTML = description;

  var button = document.getElementsByClassName('js-button');

  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].classList.remove('active-button');
  }

  elem.classList.add('active-button');
}
```

And this code for question 2:

```
<button id="choiceA" class="Button" question-two="Awnser 1" onclick="questionTwo(this)">
   Q 2 choice A
  </button>

  <button id="ChoiceB" class="Button" question-two="Awnser 2" onclick="questionTwo(this)">
    Q 2 choice B
  </button>
```

And the script:

```
function questionTwo(elem) {
  var x = document.getElementById("questionTwo");
  var description = elem.getAttribute('question-two');
  x.innerHTML = description;

  var button = document.getElementsByClassName('js-button');

  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].classList.remove('active-button');
  }

  elem.classList.add('active-button');
}
```

Comment: Please also include the logic and markup for buttons C and D.

Comment: @Taplar Done...

Comment: Do question 1 and question 2 exist on the same page?  If so you are repeating ids.

Comment: Yes it is all on one page.. which id is repeating? Sorry to ask, but I'm still learning and getting a bit cross eyed from looking at the same code..

Comment: You have `id="choiceA"` and `id="choiceB"` in both sections.  Those are repeated.  I would say change those to classes, but your logic doesn't really use them so it's not clear if they are needed at all

Comment: Also re-reading the question, you said that buttons C and D interfere with A and B, but you didn't specify how they interfere

Comment: I replaced the duplicate ID's, but still no succes...

Comment: Well, if i click on button A or B it displays/replaces the answer correct.
But after i clicked on A or B, button C and D are not working anymore.
This also goes the other way around.
So when i click button C or D first they work, but button A and B don't.

Comment: In relation to the markup and logic you have provided, what are the parts related to the "answer correct"?

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: You said it replaces the "answer correct" in your previous comment.  Its unclear to me what that refers to in your post.  I see logic for buttons, and something with `'js-button'` lookups.  Nothing about that says "answer correct" to me

Comment: Ah I understand you now.. what I mean is, that when you click button A or B the script is working correctly. But as soon as you clicked on A or B,  button C and D are not working anymore. This also goes for button C and D, when I load up the page and click on C or D first they are working correctly but button A and B are not responding anymore..

Comment: Ok, so then you're saying that clicking A/B makes C/D not work, and vise versa.  So can you elaborate on what "not working" means?

Comment: They do not respond any more, and do nothing at all..

Comment: All the buttons have inline bindings so those should still be working.  At this point I'd say throw a `debugger;` statement as the first statement in both methods, and start debugging to see what is no longer working on the second interaction

Comment: When i debug it, it comes with the following info:


**javascript.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at questionTwo (javascript.js:20)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick**

Comment: The fault should lay in the following lines:

`x.innerHTML = description;`
`onclick="questionTwo(this)">`

Comment: If `x` is null, then there was no element with that id.

Comment: Ok.. but why is it only giving that error on loading the second script? They are almost both the same.

Comment: Dunno.  You say if you click one of them first, then the other doesn't work.  That suggests the clicking of one pair destroys something the other one needs.

Comment: Hmmm, strange.. still don't get it... Do you perhaps know another way of achieving what I am looking for?

Comment: You need to figure out what is destroying the element, and fix that.

Comment: Ok I will try to.. thanks for your time and help so far! I will get back here as soon as I've fixed it.

Comment: Ahum... After staring myself blind on the javascript, and button properties i have found the issue... I accidentally placed the DIV to display the answer from button C /D inside my DIV for the answer of A/B so it kept overriding.

Thanks for keeping me sharp! And enjoy your hollidays!

Answer (score 1):

You can have question choices and a section within which the answer is going to be displayed within a `div` container. Then you can get the `div` (to display answer), by getting `parentElement` of clicked button element and then the div within it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button')
  .forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const div = this.parentElement.querySelector('div');
      div.textContent = this.dataset.ans;
    });
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="question-one"></div>
  <button class="Button" data-ans="First question choice A">choice A</button>

  <button class="Button" data-ans="First question choice B">choice B</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="question-two"></div>
  <button class="Button" data-ans="Second question choice A">choice A</button>

  <button class="Button" data-ans="Second question choice B">choice B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for thinking with me. i have tryed to implement your code but didn't get it to work?

Comment: @Taplar - Thanks :)